# Gradle Project Version vs Plugin's Gradle Version

Tags: plugins, gradle

How does the version of Gradle I use to compile a Gradle Plugin affect the users of the plugin, for example if I compile a plugin using 1.11 can I use it in a project that uses 1.6?

Is there any documentation around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle's goal is to maintain binary backwards compatibility between minor versions. That is, if you compile a plugin against 1.x, it should work with any 1.y where y >= x. There are no guarantees about the opposite direction (e.g. compiling against 1.11 and using with 1.6). This might work as long as the plugin doesn't use any APIs not available in the old version, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks Peter, is that documented anywhere?

Comment: I guess it has been mentioned here and there (e.g. in the release notes), and it's also the standard way to handle version compatibility.